# Uniqueness in IDs when display the same component on the same page

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, aura, id, aura-attribute

I've created a single 'parent' component which I'm displaying through 2 other components on one page like so:

parentComponent:

```
    <aura:component>
      <aura:attribute name="kind" type="String" />
      <div>
        <div id="{!kind + 'a div'}">
        </div>
      </div>
    </aura:component>
```

Component A:

```
    <aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
      <div>
        <c:parentComponent kind="A" />
      </div>
    </aura:component>
```

Component B:

```
    <aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
      <div>
        <c:parentComponent kind="B" />
      </div>
    </aura:component>
```

I'm displaying both A and B next to each other on one community page.

I have no problem accessing and differentiating between each instance of parentComponent due to the 'namespacing' I've given the div via id="{!kind + 'a div'}" when I try and access it from the controller and helper methods because I have access to the 'component' parameter - most of the time.

The issue is that I'm assigning a method to the document itself at some point (document.onclick = func), and then when that method is called through the document, I no longer have access to the component itself, so I don't know how to tell the difference between the instances (I want to hide/show a specifc div, for instance).

Is there any way to still be able to create uniqueness in the Ids and access them when being inside a document method and not one attached to a component?

The reason I've created the method on the document is to implement the issue here:
[hiding a div when clicking anywhere outside without using jQuery](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127004/hiding-a-div-when-clicking-anywhere-outside-without-using-jquery)

Comment: What's your JS look like so far?

Comment: I don't know if document.onclick is going to work properly under Lightning Locker anyway. You may just have to attach that handler to the highest level component you have control over. In any case what you could do is put a data-attribute on the element that is not dynamic, and your higher level handler would look for all elements with that attribute and for each one run the (if target isn't this element, hide it) logic.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I've added the dynamic IDs just now, until now they've been static since I was only using one instance of the parent component (decided to make it a parent component just now), so the code looks like this:
JS controller:
    ({
    onObjectHeaderClick: function(component, event, helper) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $A.util.toggleClass(component.find('listViewListDiv').getElement(), 'slds-hide');
        helper.addPageClick();
    }
})
and helper (splitting into the next comment as it comes out too long):

Comment: @sfdcfox
helper:

({
    closeLookup: function(event) {
        var lookupField = document.getElementById('lookupField');
        if (event.srcElement !== lookupField)
        {
            $A.util.addClass(document.getElementById('listViewListDiv'), 'slds-hide');
            document.onclick = null;
        }
    },

    addPageClick: function() {
        document.onclick = this.closeLookup;
    }
})

Comment: @CharlesT - I thought it wouldn't work either, but it seems to be working even though the lockservice is enabled.
I'm trying to create a lookup component/list thing so I need to be able to click outside the component (somewhere on the screen/page).